# Why doesn't Regex returns all matches that fits pattern?

Tags: .net, regex

I need to extract filename in those formats like filename=FileName.Extension.
I have a Regex pattern, but when I test it it returns only 1 match instead 2.
What is wrong with this pattern?

**pattern:**

```
(?<=filename=).+\..+
```

**test string:**:

`idman636build5.exe?b=1&filename=idman636build5.exeidman636build5.exe?b=1&filename=idman636build5.exe`

**Expected matches:**

- `filename=idman636build5.exeidman636build5.exe?b=1&filename=idman636build5.exe`
- `filename=idman636build5.exe`

The regex engine is .NET's default engine. I don't know the name of it.

[See the result in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/65l2U7/3/)

Comment: What regex tool or language are you using?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Oh, I see you have a link to regex101, specific to this question.Thanks, that's handy. As per [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help), you *also* need to embed pertinent information into the post itself. One reason is that should the link become unavailable, or change its content, the SO post becomes useless to future visitors, and degrades the quality of SO. Another is that no one should be required to jump around the web just to understand a question/answer. Please `edit` to include information from the external link. Your code, your result, and expected result should all be embedded

Comment: [Dave's answer below seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60125817/5411817). It looks like this case the solution works for all flavors of regex.  If you do a lot of work in .NET, [php storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) might be a better testing site, as it is specific to .NET regex, and may be more accurate for some cases.  Here are also some great references that highlights some unique traits of .NET's regex: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-csharp.html#pcre.net and https://www.rexegg.com/regex-csharp.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines.

Comment: If you want to match the filenames from the example data, perhaps use `(?<=filename=)\S+?\.exe` see  [Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dfilename%3d%29%5cS%2b%3f%5c.exe&i=idman636build5.exe%3fb%3d1%26filename%3didman636build5.exeidman636build5.exe%3fb%3d1%26filename%3didman636build5.exe) Or use a capturing group `filename=(\S+?\.exe)`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to consider the end of the filename to be the `?` or `&` character. Changing the expression to match anything up to either character:

```
(?<=filename=)[^&?]+
```

Comment: Here is a link to [this solution](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dfilename%3d%29%5b%5e%26%3f%5d%2b&i=idman636build5.exe%3fb%3d1%26filename%3didman636build5.exeidman636build5.exe%3fb%3d1%26filename%3didman636build5.exe&r=&o=n) on Regex Storm, which is an online regex tester specific to .NET

Answer (score 0):

The last `.+` will match the second one since it says match anything. `(?<=filename=).+\..+\n` this way only the first is matched for example.